# Spivak problem on property of continuous functions.

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Ok so problem goes like this:

> > If f is continuous on [0,1] and f(x) is in [0,1] for each x.Prove that f(x)=x for some x.

My proof goes like this but I am not quite sure of my result.

Let $c \in [0,1]$ and $x,x_1,x_2 \in [0,1]$ .

If f(c) = x then let $$f(x_1)<f(c)<f(x_2)$$ then by intermediate value theorem there is $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=f(c)=x$ and thus it would be proven.

I am not sure of my method thus if you could validate or correct me I would be thankful.

Reference: Spivak Calculus,chapter 7, page 117 ,exercise 11

Comment: You mean to say there exists $c$ for which $f(c)=c$?

Comment: I do not know why I did not consider other values,this is largely guesswork so I came here for rescue

Comment: Could you give the page where the problem is stated?

Comment: I will edit main answer to include reference briefly.

Comment: Spivak's exercise says "Show that $f(x)=x$ **for some number** $x$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Apply the IVT  to the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and is for **some** $x$. This point is known as fixed point of $x$.

**Edit**: We know that $g$ is continuous since $f$ and $x$ are continuous and $0\le g(0)=f(0)-0$ because $f(x)\in [0,1]$, and also $g(1)=f(1)-1\le0$, i.e., $g(1)\le0\le g(0)$ thus by the IVT there is some $c\in [0,1]$ such that $g(c)=f(c)-c=0$ as desired.

Comment: I think I found it.I would appreciate if you provided full proof so I could compare

Comment: @VanioBegic: I've edited the answer

Comment: Yes this is it,thank you for your help.It is appreciated.

Comment: @VanioBegic: You're welcome.